# External script not working (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I create external script (not in View)

Here is code of it:

```
 $('#searching').click(function () {
    $("#patients").empty();
    var lname = $("#lname").val();

    var model = {
        name: lname
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SearchingPeople", "Home")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var list = data;

            //alert(list);
            var listnumber = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
                var patientsList = ' <td class="point">' +
                    (i + 1) +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td class="title"> ' + list[i].dateOfBirth +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td class="title"> ' +
                    list[i].firstName +
                    '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + '</td>';
                $("#patients").append('<tr>' + patientsList + '</tr>');
            };
        }
    });
});
```

I call it like this in View

```
@section scripts{
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MainPageScripts/SearchScript.js")'></script>
```

}

I get this error when click on button

> POST http://localhost:51091/Home/@Url.Action(%22SearchingPeople%22,%20%22Home%22) 404 (Not Found)

If I copy this script inside View, all okay.

Why so? And how I can fix it?

Comment: `'@Url.Action("SearchingPeople", "Home")'` is razor code. Its not parsed in external files. Oneoption is to use `var url = '@Url.Action("SearchingPeople", "Home")'` in the main view and `url: url` in the script

Comment: Alternatively add a `data-url="@Url.Action("SearchingPeople", "Home")"` attribute in the element with `id="searching"` and use `$(this).data('url')` to get it